# How to position WPF control next to the control with current focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-positioning

I have a typical `edit form (user control)`, with several input boxes.
I need a `ListBox` which must show right below the `TextBox` with current focus, so it needs to move dynamically.
I tried some binding, but nothing happens

```
<local:MyList x:Name="myList"
       Canvas.Left="{Binding (FocusManager.FocusedElement).Canvas.Left,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
       Canvas.Top="{Binding (FocusManager.FocusedElement).Canvas.Bottom,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Popup` as it gives you facility to show it where you want. Its `Placement = Bottom` will show it exactly below the `PlacementTarget`.

Handle `GotFocus`, and `LostFocus` of `TextBox`.

```
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,136,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

        <Popup Placement="Bottom" x:Name="LsbPopup">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
```

Handlers :

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LsbPopup.PlacementTarget = sender as TextBox;
    LsbPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LsbPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```